# opening link with rel="" and href="" using server control button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using a Javascript package that makes a popup of inline html: http://www.enthropia.com/labs/ibox/

The following works correctly:

```
<a href="#inner_content" rel="ibox&width=800&height=400" title="Search Non Scrum Stories">Click to Open</a>
```

However, I want to be able to open the link as above by clicking a asp.net server control button:

```
<asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="Search Stories" OnClick="searchButton_Click" />
```

How do I acomplish this? I tried:

```
<a href="#inner_content" rel="ibox&width=800&height=400" title="Search Non Scrum Stories"><asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="Search Stories" OnClick="searchButton_Click" /></a>
```

and it works, but it breaks the OnClick C# ability. Also, I found out this is incorrect. So how do I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You want this to occur in the browser, not serverside, so you will not be able to use the .net OnClick.

You'll need to set the asp.net button's JS onclick behavior, and issue a click event on the link when it triggers.

With your existing code, i would do something like this:

ASPX page:

```
<a id="linkId" href="#inner_content" rel="ibox&width=800&height=400" title="Search Non Scrum Stories">Click to Open</a>

<div id="buttonContainer">
    <asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="Search Stories" />
</div>

<script>
var link = document.getElementById("linkId");
var button = document.getElementById("buttonContainer").children[0];
button.onclick = function(){link.click();}
</script>
```

Here is a working example of the js: http://jsfiddle.net/MaxPRafferty/f8jqP/